# Segmentation fault (core dumped) using async in C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, c++11

I created a function to convert an existing tree object to a string. Format of the string is

```
parent ( child1 ) ( child2 ( childOfChild2 ) )
```

The program outputs the string correctly, does some other work, but at the and crashes with

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This is the function (`getTree(this->root)` outputs whole tree):

```c++
template <typename T>
string Tree<T>::getTree(const Node<T>& node) {
    if (node.isLeaf()){
        return to_string(node.value);
    }

    vector<future<string>> results; //each element represents a subtree connected to "node"
    for (auto child:node.children){
        results.push_back(move(async(&Tree<T>::getTree,this,ref(*child))));
    }

    string children("");
    for (auto& result:results){
        children+=string(" (") + result.get()+ string(") ");     //this creates Segmentation fault, but the output is correct
        //children+=string("");                                  //this does not create Segmentation fault
        //children+=string("foo");                               //this creates Segmentation fault
    }

    return to_string(node.value)+children;
}
```

Some info about the variables:

```
vector<shared_ptr<Node>> children;
```

Please tell if you need more info. The full source is [tree.cpp](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107383231/tree.cpp) and [tree.h](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107383231/tree.h).

Comment: You don't need `move` around `async` I think.

Comment: I tried to run without the `move`, but the result is the same.

Comment: Yes yes, this wasn't a fix, just a way to write cleaner code. Does the container `node.children` remain unmodified during the whole thing?

Comment: It definitely should remain unmodified. Every modification is unintended. I will try to check it somehow.

Comment: Acknowledged. The `node.children` remain unmodified. I think it even can't be modified by definition, because the node is const.

Comment: I met similar things before, are you sure your compiler has async implemented at all or completely?

Comment: I have used an async a couple of times now on this platform and so far no problem. The future/promise mechanism works and async returns future as expected. My compiler is "gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison function in the iterator doesn't work - you also need to cover the case where both containers are empty, i.e.

```
bool operator!= (const Iter& other) const {
    if (this->queueToIter.empty()&& other.queueToIter.empty()) return false;
    if (this->queueToIter.empty()&&! other.queueToIter.empty()) return true;
    if (!this->queueToIter.empty()&& other.queueToIter.empty()) return true;
    return (this->queueToIter.front())!=(other.queueToIter.front());
};
```

Comment: Thank you, it works now. The problem was somewhere else though. Anyway, calling front() to empty vector is undefined, so this was a valid suggestion.